# VBA Code De-bugging in 2010 excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

Looking for some help in debugging some old VBA/Macro code to work in the newer version of MS Excel 2010. The macro in question is the "Material Rollup" function.

The purpose of the macro is after selecting a contiguous range of cells in a given column. Then macro will copy the information corresponding information range (B?:H?) To a new sheet or existing sheet, sort the information according to the values in the "Part #" column (D).

Up to this point the macro works as intended. But it errors out and when it tries to combine items with similar "part #" and delete the duplicate entries.  Any help or assistance you can send my way would be greatly appreciated.

The believe the errors/bug starts on the following line "Rollup, Like Part Numbers, Combine Quantities and Delete Rows".

Below is VBA code that has become the bane of my existence.

```
'**************************  Material Rollup by Part Number  *****************************
Function Material_Rollup()

    MyfirstValue = 0
    MyLastValue = 0
    Cnt = 0
    TopRow = 0
    BottomRow = 0
    CntDelRows = 0
    NewLastRow = 0
    Quantity = 0
    loopCnt = 0
    Dim MyBom As String
    Dim MyRollup As String
    Dim NextRow As String

    MyBom = ActiveSheet.Name

    If Val(Range("A2")) > 0 Or Val(Range("I1")) > 0 Then
        MsgBox MyBom & " is not a BOM72 Work sheet or Material Rollup Sheet, Rollup Canceled."
        Call GotoSheet
        GoTo Cancel
    End If

    ReturnRows (Selection.Address)
    MyfirstValue = My_First_Row
    MyLastValue = My_Last_Row

    If MyfirstValue = MyLastValue Then
        Call BOM72ERR(3, "")
        GoTo Cancel
    End If

RetrySheet:
     'Provide List of existing Sheets and input box for new Sheet Name
     ListSheets (2)

        If Pick_Sheet = "Pick_Sheet_Cancel" Then
            Sheets(MyBom).Select
            GoTo Cancel
           Else
           MyRollup = Pick_Sheet
         End If

     'See if Rollup sheet name exist or is new
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

            If UCase(sh.Name) = UCase(MyRollup) Then
                DoesSheetExist = 1
                Exit For
            Else
                DoesSheetExist = 0
            End If
    Next
    'If Sheet exist make sure its a Material Rollup Sheet
    If DoesSheetExist = 1 Then
        If Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("E1").Value <= 0 Then
                MsgBox MyRollup & " is not a Material Rollup Sheet."
        GoTo RetrySheet
        End If
    End If

    'If sheet doesn't exist, build and format
    If DoesSheetExist = 0 Then

        Sheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = MyRollup
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
        With Application
            .Calculation = xlManual
            .MaxChange = 0.001
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = False

        Worksheets("Data").Range("A4:W6").Copy (Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("A1"))

        Range("a4").Select
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

         Range("A5").Select

        TopRow = 4
        Range("E1") = TopRow
    End If

    Worksheets(MyRollup).Select
    TopRow = (Range("E1") + 1)
    BottomRow = ((Val(MyLastValue) - Val(MyfirstValue)) + 1) + Range("E1").Value
    Cnt = TopRow

    Worksheets(MyBom).Range("B" + MyfirstValue + ":H" + MyLastValue).Copy (Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("B" & TopRow))

    'Delete Rows that are not Material Items (Look for Text in Mfg Column)
    For Each C In Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("C" & TopRow & ":C" & BottomRow)

           If C.Value = "" Then
               Rows((Cnt - CntDelRows)).Select
               Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
               CntDelRows = CntDelRows + 1

            End If

               Cnt = Cnt + 1
    Next C


    'Delete Rows with the Unit Price column colored Gray (Don't Rollup)
    NewLastRow = (Cnt - (CntDelRows + 1))
    Cnt = TopRow
    CntDelRows = 0
    For Each C2 In Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("G" & TopRow & ":G" & NewLastRow)

           If C2.Interior.ColorIndex = 40 Then
               Rows((Cnt - CntDelRows)).Select
               Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
               CntDelRows = CntDelRows + 1

            End If

                Cnt = Cnt + 1

    Next C2


    NewLastRow = (Cnt - (CntDelRows + 1))


    'Sort Rollup by Part Number
    Range("A" & TopRow & ":S" & NewLastRow).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D" & TopRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    Range("B" & TopRow).Select

     Cells.Select
     With Selection.Font
         .Name = "Arial"
         .FontStyle = "Regular"
            .Size = 10
     End With
     Range("A1").Select

    Cnt = TopRow
    cnt2 = (Cnt + 1)
    CntDelRows = 0
    loopCnt = 0


    'Rollup, Like Part Numbers, Combine Quantities and Delete Rows
    For Each c1 In Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("D" & TopRow + ":D" & NewLastRow)

            NextRow = Range("D" & cnt2)

           If UCase(c1.Value) = UCase(NextRow) Then
              Quantity = Range("E" & Cnt) + Range("E" & cnt2)
              Range("E" & cnt2) = Quantity
              Rows(Cnt).Select
              Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
              CntDelRows = CntDelRows + 1
              Cnt = Cnt - 1
              cnt2 = cnt2 - 1
              Quantity = 0
           End If

             Cnt = (Cnt + 1)
             cnt2 = (cnt2 + 1)

    Next c1
        NewLastRow = NewLastRow - CntDelRows

        'Sort Rollup by Manufacturer then Part Number
        Range("A" & TopRow & ":S" & NewLastRow).Select
        Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C" & TopRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range _
        ("D" & TopRow), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

        Range("B" + TopRow).Select
        Worksheets("Data").Range("G8:W8").Copy Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("G" & TopRow & ":G" & NewLastRow)
        Sheets(MyRollup).Select

        Columns("K:S").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 6
        Columns("A").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 3
        Columns("B").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 20
        Columns("C:D").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 12
        Columns("E:F").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 6
        Columns("H").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 3

        Range("K5").Select

        With Application
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .MaxChange = 0.001
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = False
        Range("E1") = NewLastRow
        Range("A" & TopRow) = "WorkSheet: " & MyBom & "    Rows: " & MyfirstValue & " to " & MyLastValue
        Range("A" & TopRow).Font.ColorIndex = 22
        If TopRow > 5 Then
            Range("B1") = "Multi-Rollup Sheet"
            Else
            Range("B1") = "Single-Rollup Sheet"
        End If
        Range("B" + TopRow).Select
        'Don't forget to value quantity column
Cancel:
End Function
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: As-is, this is kind of "Here's some code, fix it for me".. :/  What's the actual error you get?  When you debug it and step through it, where exactly is the error thrown?  What have you tried so far in attempts to make it work?

Comment: Please supply the error message you get and which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Sorry the error is "Run-time error'13'" type mismatch.

Comment: Sorry the error is "Run-time error'13'" type mismatch. I original thought it was a simple syntax error after doing some online research. I tried changing the plus sign "+" range statement into "&". doing this would allow the macro to complete but the output was not even close to outputing the correct value or response .The error occurrs on teh following line of code. "  For Each c1 In Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("D" & TopRow + ":D" & NewLastRow) "

Comment: Screenshot your error output. Also would help to see your excel sheets for clear picture if possible upload them too.

Comment: I cut/pasted your code exactly. I made minor fixes and fixed you ranges. I cast your integers for you. This should fix it. I also added comments for possible error in code syntax so check out my comments inside the code as well. Just copy and paste into your project.

Answer (score 2):

That '+' *is* wrong.

You *concatenate strings* with `&` and *add numbers* with `+`.

Pretend TopRow = 1, and NewLastRow = 5:

You're trying to ADD "D1" to ":D5", and since you can't perform math additions on strings, you get the type mismatch error when you try.

Beyond that - output value problems without syntax errors are logic problems, to help with those, we'll need other specific information.  So those are probably best handled as new questions (with appropriate information given) so that we can deal with the problems you are encountering one at a time, after you've done your share of investigating them.  :)

Comment: i changed the '+' sybmol to '&' and it progresses further in the code sequence till it came across similar syntax errors. i have correct these error. As i mention earlier the out is nowhere near correct.

Comment: below is the information that the macro is trying to consolidate.  Item   Description Mfg Part # Quantity
   
   
               C C C 2
               A A A 1
               A A A 1
               B B B 3
               B B B 3
               C C C 2

Comment: this is the macros output:                                       Item Item Description Mfg Part # Quantity
B                B B 5
C                C C 5
C                C C 2

Comment: Yeah, one question per question. ;)   If you have a new question, post it as a new question.

Comment: well, in VBA if you are concatenating only `Strings` it is fine to use the `+`. You can't do `String` + `Integer` but it's fine for `String` + `String` + `String`

Answer (score 0):

```
 
1. I noticed a mixture of &'s and +'s.
   1a. I fixed them.

2. I think you need to cast your integers to strings (TopRow, NewLastRow, others). 
   2a. I cast them for you.
```

> I cut your code exactly.  
>  I added some comments that you will
>   see in green once you cut this and paste it.  
>  I added casting
>   to your integers in Range fields.  
> If your code is correct it
>   will now work. If it still Err's then you have to look at some logic.
>   Use some debugging to message yourself e.g. MsgBox "trying out code
>   var:" & myvar

```
Function Material_Rollup()

MyfirstValue = 0
MyLastValue = 0
Cnt = 0
TopRow = 0
BottomRow = 0
CntDelRows = 0
NewLastRow = 0
Quantity = 0
loopCnt = 0
Dim MyBom As String
Dim MyRollup As String
Dim NextRow As String

MyBom = ActiveSheet.Name

If Val(Range("A2")) > 0 Or Val(Range("I1")) > 0 Then
    MsgBox MyBom & " is not a BOM72 Work sheet or Material Rollup Sheet, Rollup Canceled."
    Call GotoSheet
    GoTo Cancel
End If

ReturnRows (Selection.Address)
MyfirstValue = My_First_Row
MyLastValue = My_Last_Row

If MyfirstValue = MyLastValue Then
    Call BOM72ERR(3, "")
    GoTo Cancel
End If
RetrySheet:

If Pick_Sheet = "Pick_Sheet_Cancel" Then
        Sheets(MyBom).Select
        GoTo Cancel
       Else
       MyRollup = Pick_Sheet
     End If

 'See if Rollup sheet name exist or is new
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        If UCase(sh.Name) = UCase(MyRollup) Then
            DoesSheetExist = 1
            Exit For
        Else
            DoesSheetExist = 0
        End If
Next
'If Sheet exist make sure its a Material Rollup Sheet
If DoesSheetExist = 1 Then
    If Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("E1").Value <= 0 Then
            MsgBox MyRollup & " is not a Material Rollup Sheet."
    GoTo RetrySheet
    End If
End If

'If sheet doesn't exist, build and format
If DoesSheetExist = 0 Then

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = MyRollup
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlManual
        .MaxChange = 0.001
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = False

    Worksheets("Data").Range("A4:W6").Copy (Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("A1"))

    Range("a4").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

     Range("A5").Select

    TopRow = 4

    'Does Range("E1") return an address or integer?
    Dim myMessage = "Range("E1") return an address or integer? TopRow = "     

    Range("E1") = TopRow

    MsgBox myMessage & TopRow

End If

Worksheets(MyRollup).Select

'
'TopRow = Address + 1? Does Range("E1") return an integer?

TopRow = (Range("E1") + 1)

MsgBox myMessage & TopRow

'Is Val(MyFirstValue), Val necessary, or help, or hinder?


BottomRow = ((Val(MyLastValue) - Val(MyfirstValue)) + 1) + Range("E1").Value
Cnt = TopRow

'Casting
Worksheets(MyBom).Range("B" + CStr(MyfirstValue) & ":H" & CStr(MyLastValue)).Copy (Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("B" & CStr(TopRow)))

'Delete Rows that are not Material Items (Look for Text in Mfg Column)
For Each C In Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("C" & CStr(TopRow) & ":C" & CStr(BottomRow))

       If C.Value = "" Then
           'Added Cast to summation
           Rows(CStr((Cnt - CntDelRows))).Select
           Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
           CntDelRows = CntDelRows + 1

        End If

           Cnt = Cnt + 1
Next C


'Delete Rows with the Unit Price column colored Gray (Don't Rollup)
NewLastRow = (Cnt - (CntDelRows + 1))
Cnt = TopRow
CntDelRows = 0

'Casting
For Each C2 In Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("G" & CStr(TopRow) & ":G" & CStr(NewLastRow))

       If C2.Interior.ColorIndex = 40 Then
           Rows((Cnt - CntDelRows)).Select
           Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
           CntDelRows = CntDelRows + 1

        End If

            Cnt = Cnt + 1

Next C2


NewLastRow = (Cnt - (CntDelRows + 1))


'Sort Rollup by Part Number
'Casting
Range("A" & CStr(TopRow) & ":S" & CStr(NewLastRow)).Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D" & TopRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

Range("B" & TopRow).Select

 Cells.Select
 With Selection.Font
     .Name = "Arial"
     .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 10
 End With
 Range("A1").Select

Cnt = TopRow
cnt2 = (Cnt + 1)
CntDelRows = 0
loopCnt = 0

'Casting
'Rollup, Like Part Numbers, Combine Quantities and Delete Rows
For Each c1 In Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("D" & CStr(TopRow) + ":D" & CStr(NewLastRow))

        NextRow = Range("D" & cnt2)

       'Casting
       If UCase(c1.Value) = UCase(NextRow) Then
          Quantity = Range("E" & CStr(Cnt)) & Range("E" & CStr(cnt2))
          Range("E" & CStr(cnt2)) = Quantity

          '?Cast here? CStr(Cnt)?

          Rows(Cnt).Select
          Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
          CntDelRows = CntDelRows + 1
          Cnt = Cnt - 1
          cnt2 = cnt2 - 1
          Quantity = 0
       End If

         Cnt = (Cnt + 1)
         cnt2 = (cnt2 + 1)

Next c1
    NewLastRow = NewLastRow - CntDelRows

    'Casting
    'Sort Rollup by Manufacturer then Part Number
    Range("A" & CStr(TopRow) & ":S" & CStr(NewLastRow)).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C" & CStr(TopRow)), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range _
    ("D" & CStr(TopRow)), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, _
    MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    'Casting
    Range("B" + CStr(TopRow)).Select
    Worksheets("Data").Range("G8:W8").Copy Worksheets(MyRollup).Range("G" & CStr(TopRow) & ":G" & CStr(NewLastRow))
    Sheets(MyRollup).Select

    Columns("K:S").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 6
    Columns("A").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 3
    Columns("B").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 20
    Columns("C:D").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 12
    Columns("E:F").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 6
    Columns("H").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 3

    Range("K5").Select

    With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .MaxChange = 0.001
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = False

    'Casting
    Range("E1") = NewLastRow          '? CStr(NewLastRow) ? Might need here!
    Range("A" & TopRow) = "WorkSheet: " & MyBom & "    Rows: " & CStr(MyfirstValue) & " to " & CStr(MyLastValue)
    Range("A" & CStr(TopRow)).Font.ColorIndex = 22
    If TopRow > 5 Then
        Range("B1") = "Multi-Rollup Sheet"
        Else
        Range("B1") = "Single-Rollup Sheet"
    End If
    Range("B" + CStr(TopRow)).Select
    'Don't forget to value quantity column
Cancel:
End Function
```